# Laravel 9 trying to access array offset on value of type int when save to database

Tags: php, laravel

my issue is when i do this --->

`$response =  Http::post('api', ['code' => $api['code']]);`

```
        $datas = json_decode($response, true);
```

`foreach ($datas as $data)
        {
            $info = new Info();
            $info['country'] = $data['country'];
            $info['code'] = $data['code'];
            $info['confirmed'] = $data['confirmed'];
            $info['recovered'] = $data['recovered'];
            $info['critical'] = $data['critical'];
            $info['deaths'] = $data['deaths'];
            $info->save();
        }
</code>`

i get an error :: trying to access array offset on value of type int
how can i fix this? i try to save this to database (this is come from post method)
my tables of country and code has 'string' types and confirmed recovered and etc which is below is bigInteger types? whats an issue??

Comment: hi can you share me more details about you model structure $ what is the response getting back from that  'Http::post('api', ['code' => $api['code']]);' this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, remove decode parameter to take object (this post method uses objects)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).